# Kafka consumer synchronization behavior

Tags: asynchronous, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am currently exploring kafka as a beginner for a simple problem.

> There will one *Producer* pushing message to one *Topic* but there will
>   be *n* number of *Consumer* of spark application massage the data from
>   kafka and insert into database (each consumer inserts to different
>   table).
>
> Is there a possibility that consumers will go out of sync (like some part of the consumer goes down for quite some time), then
>   one or more consumer will not process the message and insert to table
>   ?
>
> assuming the code is always correct, no exception will arise when
>   massaging the data. It is important that every message is processed
>   only once.

My question is that does Kafka handles this part for us or do we have to write some other code to make sure this does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group consumers (see `group.id` config) and that grouped consumers split topic's partitions among themselves. Once a consumer drops, another consumers from the group will take over partitions read by dropped one.

However, there may be some problems: when consumer read a partition it commit offset back to Kafka and if consumer dropped after it processed received data but before commit offset, other consumers will start read from the latest available offset. Fortunately, you can manage strategy of how offset is committed (see consumer's settings `enable.auto.commit`, `auto.offset.reset` etc)

[Kafka and Spark Streaming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) provide some explanations and possible strategies of how to manage offsets.

Comment: Looks like Kafka is unable to guarantee the message only once but at least once delivery.

Comment: Yes. It is cost of distribution and high performance. You have to do it by yourself if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

By design Kafka decouples the producer and the consumer.  Consumer will read as fast as they can - and consumers can produce as fast as they can.

Consumers can be organized into "consumer groups" and you can set it up so that multiple consumers can read from a single group as well set it up so that an individual consumer reads from its own group.

If you have 1 consumer to 1 group you (depending on your acknowledgement strategy) should be able to ensure each message is read only once (per consumer).

Otherwise if you want multiple consumer reading from a single group - same thing - but the message is read once by a one of n consumers.